# "Cannot resolve R" everywhere after converting module from application to feature

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add instant app functionality to my project. So I am following the instructions given in this tutorial : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0

The fifth chapter explains how to move the existing code from an application module to a feature module. I'm following this tutorial step-by-step, updating both the playground `topeka` project given with this tutorial and my project. However, I'm stuck after the first sub-chapter **"Convert the app module into a feature module called topeka-base"**.

After renaming my `project` folder to `project-base`, and transforming it from `com.android.application` to `com.android.feature`, the Gradle sync runs fine but I can't rebuild my project anymore, since every occurrence of `my.project.R` get a `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'` error. I'm not having this problem with the `topeka` app that comes along with the tutorial, however.

As you can see below, there is no such error in `topeka` project:

[image]

So I tried looking at my project generated files to find a difference, but actually I don't see any difference with `topeka`:

```
package my.project;

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "my.project";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 38;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.9.0";
}
```

So what could be the reason? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first start with trying to clean and then rebuild the project sometimes it fixes the issue.
You can also try invalidating the caches and restarting the android studio.
Also, I guess you should check the manifest file and edit the app's name there.

Comment: Have you also checked res>values>strings.xml and changed the app's name there?

Comment: I'm not having any issue with `strings.xml` actually, the problem seems to be from the generated `R`

Comment: @Someday have you managed to solve this after all? I'm in the exact situation as you are. There should be dependencies in the feature modules to reference R from the base module, and not viceversa. But even that doesn't work for me